# How to adjust the memory size in a char array which is created by a function?

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management

I call a method with:

```
char * buffer = read_string_from_file();
```

Here is the method:

```
char * read_string_from_file() {
    char * filename = "C:/Users/xxxxx/Dropbox/c-programming-test-file.txt";  // later I will give this as a parameter
    char * buffer = 0;
    long file_length;
    FILE * file = fopen (filename, "r");

    if (file)
    {
        fseek (file, 0, SEEK_END);
        file_length = ftell (file);
        fseek (file, 0, SEEK_SET);
        buffer = malloc (file_length);
        if (buffer)
        {
            fread (buffer, 1, file_length, file);
        }
        fclose (file);
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

The file contains:

```
2461866 -3134537
```

When printing the `buffer` with `printf("buffer: %s\n\n", buffer);` I get `buffer: 2461866 -3134537Files\Jey┘·å¬`. Instead I expected: `buffer: 2461866 -3134537`. How do I adjust the size of the char array `buffer`?

Comment: You don't terminate the string properly, and you don't even check if `fread()` worked.  You're also opening the file in text mode, so `ftell()` doesns't tell you how many bytes will be read.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I am still a beginner. :| How to not open it in text mode? With "b"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `printf("buffer: %s\n\n", buffer);`, `"%s"` needs `buffer` to point to a string.  In OP's case, it is not, thus UB (extra junk printed).

---

If the length can be known, simply print with `fwrite()`

```
fwrite(buffer, 1, file_length, stdout);
```

**or** as `buffer` is not certainly a *string*, code could use the following if `file_length < INTMAX`.

```
printf("%.*s", (int) file_length, buffer);
```

**or** change `read_string_from_file()` to form a *string*.  Append a *null character*.

```
// buffer = malloc (file_length);
buffer = malloc (file_length + 1);
if (buffer) {
  fread (buffer, 1, file_length, file);
  // add
  buffer[file_length] = '\0';
  ...
  printf("buffer: %s\n", buffer);
```

---

Without  a *null character*, `buffer` is not a *string*.

---

Aside: Robust code would check the results of `ftell(), fread()` too.

Comment: Okay I will repeat this sentence. Without a null character, buffer is not a string. Without a null character, buffer is not a string. Without a null character, buffer is not a string. Without a null character, buffer is not a string. :) One of the biggest beginner mistakes right?

Comment: @kane Detail: the data contents of a file are rarely a _string_ (text up to an including a null character).  A text file is more often many _lines_ (text up to and including a `'\n'` except maybe the last line).  To  certainly print all the file (which might expectantly contains null characters, use the `fwrite()` approach.

Comment: kane, Yes, not minding the _null character_ requirement of a _string_ is a common oops.

Comment: Thank you for the good hint about many null characters in a file. (btw. Kame, not Kane) :)

Comment: Ooos, meant "which might **un**expectantly contains null characters"

Answer (score 1):

In C strings must be NUL terminated.

You can do this for example:

```
...
buffer = malloc (file_length + 1);  // + 1 for the NUL terminator
buffer[file_length] = 0;            // put NUL terminator
...
```

Comment: When I use your code it is working with only 6 numbers. When I have 60 numbers in the file the problem occurs again. Could you check this please?

Comment: @kame show a minimal file that produces the problem. Otherwise you might want look into `fgets`.